# phrase highlight QEditText PyQt4 Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, nltk

I am creating a GUI application in python 3.4 using PyQt4 GUI-tool & NLTK. Here below i am explaining what task i have to perform in my application and what part i have completed:

Goal:

1) User will create category and provide very large text to save into database

2) based on uploaded text, user will search phrases( group of words). Phrases can occur on multiple line.

3) matched phrases list will be maintain according to lines where they found on document.

4) When user will select matched phrase line, cursor should move to that matched phrase line and highlight that phrase.

Completed:

1) I can upload documents and search phrase based on matched line.

2) and highlight in QEditText text box

Issue:
1) I am not able to highlight phrase. It only highlights single word from phrase

Code provided below what i have perform to highlight phrase:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

import string
# list view class
from view_matched_phrases_ui import Ui_ViewList
from PyDB import DatabaseHandle



class ViewList(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ViewList, self).__init__(parent)
        self.list = Ui_ViewList()
        self.list.setupUi(self)

    def show_list(self, phrases):
        # self.list.phrase_text_view.setText("<div>Hello</div> Sahadev")

        # cursor = self.list.phrase_line_view.setCursor()
        # cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.Start)
        # self.list.phrase_text_view.setTextCursor(curson)

        ids = phrases[1]['pid']

        with DatabaseHandle() as db:
            for id in ids:
                sql = "SELECT document FROM contracts WHERE id="+str(id)
                data = db.get_single_data(sql)

                phrase_data = str.maketrans({key: None for key in string.punctuation})
                new_s = data[0].translate(phrase_data).lower()

                for line in new_s.splitlines():
                    if phrases[0].replace('_', ' ') in line:
                        self.list.phrase_line_view.addItem(line)

        # set selected contract in QTextEdit
        self.list.phrase_text_view.setPlainText(new_s)

        # self.list.phrase_text_view

        cursor = self.list.phrase_text_view.textCursor()

        # setup match
        format = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        format.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("yellow")))
        # Setup the regex engine
        pattern = phrases[0].replace("_", " ")

        regex = QtCore.QRegExp(pattern)
        # Process the displayed document
        pos = 0

        index = regex.indexIn(self.list.phrase_text_view.toPlainText(), pos)

        while index != -1:
            # Select the matched text and apply the desired format

            cursor.setPosition(index)
            cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.EndOfWord, 1)

            cursor.mergeCharFormat(format)
            # Move to the next match
            pos = index + regex.matchedLength()
            index = regex.indexIn(self.list.phrase_text_view.toPlainText(), pos)

        # print(self.list.phrase_text_view)
        # print(phrases)
```

This contribution will be great help for me.

Comment: I have solved this issue. Thanks for watching this problem

Comment: 1. don't just use a version-specific python tag, always use the generic [python] tag too. So undoing the previous edit was harmful. 2. If your comment suggests that the problem is solved, you should either delete your question or post an answer to it yourself if you think that it could help future readers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. I will update the code..

Comment: Since the question is here to stay, I took the liberty of reintroducing the generic python tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by counting phrase length and nextWord method with Qt Text Object.

Rest of the code will be same only changes part i am providing here:

```
while index != -1:
        # Select the matched text and apply the desired format
        cursor.setPosition(index)
        # go to next word
        for i in range(len(self.matched_phrase.split(" "))):
            cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextWord, 1)
            cursor.mergeCharFormat(format)

        # Move to the next match
        pos = index + regex.matchedLength()
        index = regex.indexIn(self.list.phrase_text_view.toPlainText(), pos)
```